# Twitter Bootstrap typeahead getting id post data

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am using Twitter Bootstrap typeahead, following this example.

```
var mySource = [{ id: 1, name: 'Terry'}, { id: 2, name: 'Mark'}, { id: 3, name: 'Jacob'}];

$('#myElement').typeahead({
    source: mySource
});
```

I need to write the "id" of the selected "name" to a table on submit. It is trying to write the "name" to the table on submit and I am not sure what else to try. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code your using to write to the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality of bootstrap typeahead is very minimal. What you want can't be done without modifying the plugin's source code.

Instead you could use Select2 for bootstrap, which can do that out of the box. http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/